# trying to new generated print url after login python selenium webdriver

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs


#for logging into chrome or firefox browser, user can use other browser like chrome by appropriately adding corresponding webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#Always a constant for unique user_id and can be found by logging in kiteconnect. Paste the redirect-url below at time of logging
#into kiteconnect. It's a one time activity.

driver.get("https://kite.trade/connect/login?api_key=XXXXYYYYXXX")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/input')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/input')

username.send_keys("My_userid")
password.send_keys("my_passwad")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/button').click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

Security1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/input')
Security2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/input')

Security1.send_keys("Answers")
Security2.send_keys("Answers")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/button').click()


driver.implicitly_wait(10)


print browser.current_url
```

it s printing wrong URL 
mentioned above code i am using  to auto login after login i want print "request_token=XXXXJHGWJH " print from URL

Comment: So, what went wrong when you executed your code? Did it throw an exception? Did it print the wrong url?

Comment: yes it printed wrong url - it printed old , not new url it printed

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong with the piece of code you posted. `print(browser.current_url)` should do exactly what you want. Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: print(browser.current_url)
NameError: name 'browser' is not defined

Comment: ...that's the code from your question, you know? Anyway, we still need a [mcve].

Comment: i have edited and pasted my code

Comment: Hmm, well, I can't test it without an API key, but I really don't see anything wrong with the code. Sorry!

Comment: API Key - "MY API CODE

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to post that...

Comment: do we need add anything more , after generating new URL print

Comment: Well, I'm having trouble getting selenium to work, but it doesn't really matter because I can't test it without knowing your user id and password anyway. Looks like you'll have to debug this on your own.